# Warning " X is rank deficient to within machine precision" problem

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression, rank

I am trying to build a multiple linear regression in MATLAB with 20 predictors, which are categorical with 4 levels each. I am using the function "regress", like this (these are not the actual variables):

X = [ones(size(x1)) x1 x2 x3...x20];
[b,bint,r,rint] = regress(Y, X);

Before this, I transformed the vectors x1,x2...x20 in categorical variables with dummyvar.

I get this error and a lot of 0's in the b coefficients and this error:

*Warning: X is rank deficient to within machine precision.*

In the dummyvar documentation it is mentioned:
*To use the dummy variables in a regression model, you must either delete a column (to create a reference group) or fit a regression model with no intercept term.*

I tried not using the intercept ones(size(x1)) and I get the same error.

I would appreciate any input on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify the problem down to the minimum working example, and then post that here, so we can reproduce it and help you through. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)
for examples of rank deficiency.